# Как отследить созданные блоки js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При нажатии на кнопку "ADD", создаются новые элементы. Как их отследить и работать с ними (менять, удалять и т.д.)?

```js
$(function() {
  $('a.pts').click(function() {
    var obj = this;
    var inputPts = $('input').val();
    var points = $('div.mmr').append("<p>" + inputPts + "</p>");
  });
})
$(function() {
  $('a.pts1').click(function() {
    var newtext = $('div').html();
    localStorage.po1 = newtext
  });
})

$('div.mmr').append(localStorage.po1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="pts">ADD</a>
<a href="#" class="pts1">UPDATE</a>
<div class="mmr"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавляйте ссылкe на элемент в какой-нибудь массив (объект). Так получите доступ к элементу и сможете с ним работать

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const container = document.getElementById('divs-container');
const divsTemp = [];
let globalCounter = 0

btn.onclick = function () {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = `Я созданный блок: ${globalCounter++}`;
  container.appendChild(div);
  divsTemp.push(div);
}

const clearTimer = setInterval(() => {
  if(!divsTemp.length) return;
  const div = divsTemp.shift(); // получаем первый элемент, попутно удаляя его из массива
  container.removeChild(div);
}, 500);
```

```html
<button id='btn'>Создать блок</button>
<div id='divs-container'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться `MutationObserver`, который уже давно поддерживается всеми рабочими браузерами. А кроме того, он делает работу с dom-элементами не просто легче, но ещё правильней. Намного правильней, когда dom-контейнер при помощи событий говорит о том, что происходит за его инкапсуляцией.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let rect = document.createElement('div');

  container.appendChild(rect);
});

let observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  mutations.forEach(({
    addedNodes
  }) => {
    addedNodes.forEach(element => element.classList.add('rect'))
  });
});

let config = {
  childList: true
};

observer.observe(container, config);
```

```css
.rect {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: tomato;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<button>add</button>
```